# Generate javadoc comments from command line

Tags: java, javadoc, generate

**EDIT**
*(Again to emphasize that this is planned to be used on getters and setters model classes that are completely fine with auto-generated comments that will not bring any value. So please give info if you know tool or way to do this, do not go into the discussion 'if should be done'. I already know that it should not!)*

There are many solutions that provide auto-generation for java-doc comments especially plugins for eclipse or intellyJ. The comments should simple as comments on getter/setter.
For example

```
  /**
   * Gets name.
   *
   * @return the name.
   */
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
```

But what I struggle with is to find a solution that can run as a script from the command line.

What I want to achieve is to be able to run the script on SomeClassName.java like

```
$ ./addAutoGeneratedComments -i SomeClassName.Java -o SomeClassName2.java
```

I spent countless hours to find such a solution or a nice guide for this but I was not able to find one. The closest thing that I found is https://github.com/setial/intellij-javadocs.git I am not able to compile it.

I would really appreciate some help, some link with this kind of topic would be enough for me to start from somewhere.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this? Automatically generated comments are rarely useful to others (the example you provided is a good example of this - the comment doesn't say anything that you wouldn't already know from the method's name).

Comment: Adding those auto-generated comments has no value. Why would you do that? It offers no information value over having no javadoc comments, because all information is directly inferred from the signature.

Comment: IMO javadocs like that are not only useless, they clutter the code

Comment: For the love of heaven, please stop writing comments like that.  They tell the reader nothing.  They’re worse than nothing, because it means someone knew that a comment was needed and explicitly chose to insult the reader by telling them nothing.  That comment should explain whether the name can be null, whether it has length restrictions, whether it has character restrictions, whether it’s supposed to be human readable, whether it came from user input, and whether it’s a unique identifier for the object.

Comment: Legacy code, tons of getters and setters need to have comments. It is useful to make the boss happy. To me zero value + lots of useless effort.

Comment: If the boss wants documentation, they probably want it so the code will be readable and usable by others.  Auto-generated parrot comments will not provide that.  But, feel free to explain to the boss that meaningful documentation will take a long time, whereas useless parrot docs will be much quicker but will have no value and will defeat the point of having documentation.  At least if the boss makes the decision about which approach to take, the technical debt will be the boss’s fault.

Comment: I know all you say. But this is mainly for getters and setters. Auto-generated won't be used for the code with use-cases. There are 1000+ classes with models that have arguments like name, age, address, phone, bla bla. All self explanatory. But it would be nice if we have way to auto-generate those getters and setters comments.

Comment: It would be perfect, if there would be a command line tool which generates Javadoc for getters and setters on the fly only in order to create HTML doc. Something like `add-getter-and-setter-comments src/ | javadoc` or `add-getter-and-setter-comments src/ tmp/ && javadoc tmp/ ; rm -fr tmp`.